# Recieving emails from my website through flask?

Tags: python, html, forms, email, flask-mail

I have an email form on my webpage where the goal is for users to be able to send my account an email. They give me their email but is there a way to send a message from their email to my email without their password. All i'm seeing online is code to send out emails through flask not recieve. What work arounds do you guys suggest where I can have users send me an email through my website.

Comment: This is really interesting question but I don't think you will be able to use user's email account to send email to your email account. One way could be that save those entries in the database and then send emails from flask to your email account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is not possible.
Otherwise you would have "access" on their account and could write mails to everyone you want.

A solution would be to save the message in the database and if you need it, you can send the message to you, with all the needed information, by your own mail adresse (like AKA commented).